# Find when ceiling functions differ by one

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

For the function $$f(x) = (a/b)x + (c/b)$$

how do I find the smallest value x such that:

$$\lceil f(x)\rceil  < \lceil f(x) + kx\rceil $$

where 
x is a positive integer, 
a, b, and c are integers, 
c/b < 1, and 
k is a positive rational less than 1?

Written another way:
$$\lceil f(x)\rceil  + 1 = \lceil f(x) + kx\rceil $$
or
$$\lceil (a/b)x + (c/b)\rceil + 1 = \lceil (a/b)x + (c/b) + kx\rceil$$

If you have a solution, or if you're just in a hurry, you might want to skip the rest of this. The reason I'm asking is because I want to find the summation of all the values within a given range of the ceiling of f(x). My solution was to brute force the answer from 0 to b (count them one at a time), then calculate the rest because after b it repeats geometrically. But this doesn't work when b is very large, because then I end up brute forcing the entire thing.

My current plan is to approximate the slope with a smaller denominator so I can do the above solution for a portion of the range. For instance:
$$f(x) = (172592/179897)x + (108554/179897)$$
179897 is too large to brute force. An approximation is:
$$ g(x) = (189/197)x + 108554/179897$$
The slopes are off by a difference of k, which is roughly 0.000002.

Thus, the difference between f(x) and g(x) is k:
$$f(x) = g(x) + kx$$
They have the same ceiling function until the point where f(x) is within kx of the next integer.

Update: 
I just realized my function can be simplified. In the problem statement, the lines come from vertices of a triangle at integer coordinates, so the denominator of the slope and the denominator of the intercept are the same, since both are x1-x2. I'll fix the question above.

Comment: I personally think nothing can be done about this, other than to find the best approximation to the slope, as you have done, for a certain problem.

Comment: Never mind. I've solved it another way that doesn't use an approximation.

Comment: Happy to know that.How have you solved it?

Comment: I explained my solution in the description of my other question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1750324/summation-over-a-floor-function-of-a-first-degree-polynomial).

Comment: As you said in your post, it turned out to be very easy. Nice.Besides, I worked a lot on this question in the middle, but did not find anything conclusive. Thank you for taking my time constructively, and +1.